# JSON.parse - Unexpected token ', n

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

When I tried to send to my express server JSON like this one:

```
"{ name: '...', description: '...' }"
```

This error had been throwed:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token n ...
```

Trying to parse JSON like this in Chrome:

```
"{ 'name': '...', 'description': '...' }"
```

Leads to this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' ...
```

Why parsing those JSONs leads to an error? Especially the second JSON looks valid (using `'` instead of `"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use single quotes in JSON. String values and keys must be enclosed in double quotes.

> A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be nested.
>
> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes. A character is represented as a single character string. A string is very much like a C or Java string.
>
> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins with { (left brace) and ends with } (right brace). Each name is followed by : (colon) and the name/value pairs are separated by , (comma).
>
> [image: JSON Object]

Quotes from [json.org](https://www.json.org/)